# Instagram getting token in iOS issue

Tags: ios, swift3, instagram, instagram-api

I made a request to instagram  using the following url:

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=98967dce3d2847c9aefff2342e92d5eb&redirect_uri=http://www.getartup.com/&response_type=code
```

On browser i'm able to retrieve code as

```
http://www.getartup.com/?code=0ce2113308ee4376ae10f9f45e9767b6
```

but while making request in uiwebview i'm not able to catch the code .

Any one facing the same problem.

Regards.

Comment: uiwebview - bad choice use datawithrequest

Comment: so u want to access token right?

Comment: @Purushothaman yes i need token

Comment: did u tried it let me know after complete @user3804063

Comment: @Purushothaman you didn't get  my question or i couldn't make you understand my question

Answer (score 0):

Go to his link

[click here](http://dmolsen.com/2013/04/05/generating-access-tokens-for-instagram/)

After you got the code you can use

```
curl -F 'client_id=[your_client_id]' -F 'client_secret=[your_secret_key]' -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' -F 'redirect_uri=[redirect_url]' -F 'code=[code]' https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```